# How to access textview value which is inside tableview cell in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, tablecell

I have one viewcontroller, inside that I have one table view and 2 buttons save and cancel.
In tableview cell i have one textview. after adding some text in textview i want to show that text. I am not sure how to get that tableview text on save button click. (number of rows may be dynamic).

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                if let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SummaryManualEditContentCell", for: indexPath) as? SummaryManualEditTableCell {


                    cell.txtAnswers.text = "enter text here"

                    return cell
                }
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

@IBAction func btnSave(_ sender: Any) {
        print("textviewText1 + textviewText2 + and so on ")
   }
```

In Addition to this on button click i want to add all that text multiple textviews into one string.
is there any clean and best way to achieve this?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Since you populate the text views from the model you have to implement a logic which updates the model when the text changes in the cell. Otherwise scrolling will cause unexpected behavior. In `btnSave` get the data from the model, not from the view.

Comment: @vadian Thanks..but just want to show text which I am getting from textviews.. its ok if you dont consider for model for now. I updated my question

Comment: Considering the model is crucial. As I said scrolling doesn't work properly if you don't update the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the indexPath of the cell whose text you want to get 
get the cell for that indexpath like

```
@IBAction func btnSave(_ sender: Any) {
      let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
      if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SummaryManualEditTableCell {
        let text = cell.txtAnswers.text
        }
    }
```

And if you have multiple cells with textFields you can loop around to get all fields

```
  @IBAction func btnSave(_ sender: Any) {
var allTextViewsText = ""
       for i in 0...5{
          let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
          if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SummaryManualEditTableCell {
            allTextViewsText += cell.txtAnswers.text
            }
        }
  print(allTextViewsText)
}
```

But keep it in mind that this approach only works in the case of visible cells otherwise for non visible cells you will get nil

I will suggest you to implement textView:shouldChange in each cell who has `textView` with a delegate to the tableView's viewController. When text is changed in the cell, delegate should propagate the change to the viewController which will save the value in a variable.

Then, when you press on the save button, you would simply take values from variables.

Comment: Thanks but How to get that ..by using your answer its not clear..giving error on indexpath. Can you please elaborate

Comment: check the answer now